# Azure Functions V4 not showing functions via Linux

Tags: javascript, typescript, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I'm currently attempting to deploy very simple functions to Azure Functions V4 using Typescript. The functions is the boilerplate `timerTrigger` and and `httpTrigger`.

I'm deploying the code using `func azure functionapp publish` but I have also used `az functionapp deployment source config-zip` with no luck, I have also trying deploying using SCM. Functions are not showing up in dashboard and there's nothing in the "Log Stream".

Everything runs fine locally using `func start` (using azurite). I've even managed to get the function to put a file in blob storage.

I have also tried deploying using the V3 model (using javascript and typescript), in those cases the functions show up for javascript, but they do not get invoked.

My question is, am I missing a fine detail somewhere? Am I missing a step?

My App Settings are as follows:

[image]

The code/structure:

[image]

And not sure if completely relevant by my host.json:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    },
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information",
      "Function": "Information",
      "Host.Results": "Information"
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  }
}
```

output from the publish command:

[image]

Comment: What is the response from the CLI when deploying the apps?

Comment: Also note that `extensionBundle.version` has a typo in it - a closing `)` instead of `]`

Comment: Nice catch, the typo was auto generated by `func init` from the function tools cli. I've fixed the typo and pushed but no changes there. I've added an edit with the output let me know if you'd like the verbose version.

Comment: Looks like deployment works, its perhaps unable to start the process. In the azure portal UI, do you see any notifications for the azFunc? Eg. https://i.imgur.com/VrMbe52.png (Not that I'm suggesting your app is stopped, this is just a demo image)

Comment: the closing`)` is not a typo btw.

Comment: Really? Ok, my bad.

Comment: There are no Notifications

Comment: @Parham Can you try to deploy with [this](https://i.imgur.com/NrkT40T.png) option as I am able to see the functions with this deployment option

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin I just gave it a go but still no luck, this is the output https://imgur.com/a/Cl8l0dJ

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin that did trigger this however in the stream logs: https://imgur.com/QOkqkgQ (still no functions showing up in the portal)

Comment: One other relevant piece of info would be that I'm running Linux as the function's OS, I tried running the app with Windows and it showed up.

Comment: @Parham With Linux OS also, [functions](https://i.imgur.com/KWYlJxs.png) are showing for me

Comment: So I did a bit more playing around and confirmed issue was the `extensionBundle.version` in host.js. It works on Linux with: "version": "[3.15.0, 4.0.0)" so it's a bug with `azure-functions-core-tools` generating the wrong version via `func init`

Comment: I'll have to investigate later but one other possible explanation could be that the publish via the cli doesn't sync the triggers and once you use VSCode to deploy those triggers will exist and from that point you can deploy successfully using the cli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a Model V4 typescript function using visual studio code which is having below files post enabling Azurite -

[image]

I have created two default Timer and Http triggered function.

My host.json and tsconfig.json looks like below

**host.json**-

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**-

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": false
  }
}
```

**App settings**-

[image]

**Deployment**-

I am using `func azure functionapp publish func-app-name` command to deploy the functions to a Linux Function App.

[image]

Functions are showing-

[image]

I am getting output as shown below-

[image]

Even I used below option in vs code to deploy my function and it worked as well.

[image]

[image]